# How to configure docker for multiple user groups (sudo and non-sudo) with copy/commit restrictions?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am setting up a GPU server wherein students can login via ssh and run tasks on GPU. The student accounts do not have administrative rights. However, once they are added to the docker group, they can have access to the docker images and containers that are currently being used by the administrative accounts. Is there any way of compartmentalizing their docker access to only specific images and also prevent them from modifying/copying from other users ?

Comment: using some tricks, maybe, but docker does not provide this, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: For the time being, I will rely probably on the good will of students and hope they dont screw up base images by explicitly making clones and very specific docker run and commit scripts. If I happen to find a solution in the near future, I will update.